# dicord.js bot joins a channel when a specific user joins a channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have been having many issues having my bot join a channel whenever a specific user joins a channel. The idea is to have the bot follow around a specific user. What I have done is use VoiceState to check if users are joining and leaving a channel and trying to get the IDs of the members coming and going. I have gotten some progress using this method, but I am stuck and can't figure out if there is a better way to do this. Any help is appreciated :)

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if (newState.channelId === null) {
        //if user leaves leave
        console.log('user left channel', oldState.channelId);
    }
    //if specified user joins bot joins
    else if (oldState.channelId === null) {
        console.log('user joined channel', newState.channelId);
        let users = newState.channel.members;
        let ids = users.keys();
        console.log(ids);

        if (//target id is in id's)
            {
                //then bot joins
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was using  `.member` for voicestate and from there using `.id` hope this helped anyone with the same issue :)

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
        if (newState.channelId === null) {
            //if user leaves leave
            console.log('user left channel', oldState.channelId);
        }
        //if F0re joins bot joins
        else if (oldState.channelId === null) {
            console.log('user joined channel', newState.channelId);
    
            let member = newState.member;
    
            let targetID = member.id;
    
            if (targetID == TARGET) {
                join.joinChannelViaChannel(newState.channel);
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('user moved channels', oldState.channelId, newState.channelId);
        }
    });
```